# Simple NGINX setup not working

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

So I am new to NGINX, and I am trying to setup a simple phpinfo page in `/home/codehitman/nginx/phpinfo` directory. I have setup the `/etc/hosts` file with the following directive:

```
127.0.0.1    phpinfo.local
```

And here is the conf file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  phpinfo.local;

    root   /home/codehitman/nginx/phpinfo;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/localhost.error.log;

    location / {
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass  localhost:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME
                      $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include       fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

The virtual host file has been softlinked to the sites-enabled folder and the server has been restarted with a `[OK]`. But whenever I go to the page I keep seeing the default nginx page. I don't see the log files being generated but if I `tail` the default logs then I see this:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jan/2016:22:03:20 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0"
```

When I inspect the headers in the browser's developer tools, then I see a `GET` request for `/` and not `phpinfo.local`. I have also changed the ownership and permissions to the nginx directory in my home directory:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/codehitman/nginx
sudo chmod -R 777 /home/codehitman/nginx
```

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Cheers!

**EDIT:**
So I figured out the reason why this wasn't working the first time. I had softlinked it wrong. Now that it is linked correctly, I am getting a 502 Bad gateway error with this in the log:

```
2016/01/02 22:52:36 [error] 18653#0: *16 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: phpinfo.local, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "phpinfo.local"
```

Comment: Remove the default configuration and try tailing the error log. Everything looks right there to me.

Comment: Okay figured out why I was getting the 304s  in the log. I didn't softlink correctly. Instead of `ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/phpinfo sites-enabled`, I did `ln -s sites-available/phpinfo ...` from the nginx directory.

Comment: Your problem now is probably in your php-fpm conf. You might want to edit the question to include that info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! I had to replace the `.php` with this:

```
location ~ .php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Also make the following changes to the `default` virtualhost:

```
# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

    # With php5-cgi alone:
    #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    # With php5-fpm:
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

I got the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15854491/3199478